# Why does `git rebase` not show stats?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I've noticed that `git pull` shows a summary of changed files in the output, but `git rebase` (or `git pull --rebase`) doesn't.

This seems inconsistent to me.

I wonder what's the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> - #### rebase.stat
>
>   Whether to show a diffstat of what changed upstream since the last rebase. False by default.

---

`git pull --rebase` will pull all the changes from the server and then place your changes on top of it.

The default `--stat` option for merge (`pull` = `fetch+merge`) `merge.stat`, defualt  value is **true**.
The default `--stat` option for `git rebase` is: `rebase.stat`, default to value is **false**.

If you manually add `--stat` to your `git pull` line, the `pull` script passes this option on to either `git merge` or `git rebase` (whichever one it runs).  If you *leave this option out*, git relies on a default option.